# View/download PHP uploads - how to do it virus safe?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, upload, virus

Now I've read a bunch of SO topics on how to check whether PHP uploads are virus safe and the gist from that is: I can't 100% guarantee that uploads aren't full of viruses - no matter the extension. One proposed solution is to remove the extension during the upload and then reassemble it when people want to download.

However, I want to let users view files directly on the website. How do I go about doing that? For example, generating an iframe with an uploaded PDF inside - is that safe or is it like executing it which would give potential viruses the opportunity to spread? With DOCs I wanted to use Google Docs, so I'd embed an iframe of Google Docs which GETs a URL of the DOC on my server. Is that safe then?

Or is there simply no way other than only allowing downloads to prevent potential viruses from spreading on the server? If so, how goes the reassembling of the extension? I'd guess, when someone uploads a test.exe, I'd remove the .exe part but store in a database. Then when someone requests the download, i rename the test file to test.exe and push the download. After that I rename it back to test. Is that correct?

Also: how do services like Trello do this? When I upload an image file there, it gets shown directly - without noticeable delay through virus scans or whatever. I thought about using the virustotal.com API but that certainly takes quite long, doesn't it? Would it be okay though to let people upload, then not show them publicly until a virustotal.com-scan is done and then consider the file safe?

Thanks and cheers for all help and sorry, if I missed something.

Comment: Understand one thing... *File extensions don't have anything to do with anything.*  Aside from that, the only way to "clean" a file of viruses is to run it through some kind of virus scanner.  If the scanner finds something, reject the file.  If you're allowing users to save files on your server then those files can literally contain *anything*.  Unless you examine or modify those files in any way, users will download exactly what was uploaded.

Comment: no. you don't rename the files, period. they're on the server. they can't hurt the user. you can tell the client ANY name for when they download the file, e.g. `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="cutekittens_with_virus.exe"); readfile('totally_different_filename');`

Comment: Well, I totally mixed something up here for sure. You're correct - renaming was a proposed solution to prevent files from executing ON the server, but it doesn't spare the user of virus pain. So to sum up: I'm letting them upload, I'm not renaming, then I'm not gonna show anything publicly until virustotal.com told me I'm good - and if not, I immediately delete the file(s). The files are landing in randomly named folders, so users shouldn't be able to find them by theirselves - am I safe to assume my server doesn't get injected as long as the files don't get executed?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches I've seen in practice over the years:

1. Scan it locally, using e.g. ClamAV.

   - Pro: If your virus detections are up-to-date, you'll catch any known viruses this way.
   - Con: Anti-virus software is an attack surface. See many of the findings of [Tavis Ormandy](https://twitter.com/taviso) from Google Project Zero.
   - Con: Could be taxing to server resources. (Maybe spin up a different server dedicated to AV purposes?)
2. Use an API, such as VirusTotal.

   - Pro: Less attack surface.
   - Con: You have to share the file with VirusTotal, which might be a bad idea if the files you're letting users upload are particularly sensitive (i.e. protected health information).

I'm not sure which to recommend, because I don't know your threat model or operational constraints.

However, the more general problem of **not serving browser exploits (e.g. XSS) or allowing reverse shells on the server** is actually [somewhat easy](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/12/2018-guide-building-secure-php-software#secure-php-files), but not trivial.